# In Google sheets create a radar chart with text labels

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I am trying to create a radar chart like this: [image: radar chart]

but I cannot work out how to add labels to the axis, is there any way to do this in google sheets?

Comment: side note: what kind of graph is this? It doesn't seem to convey any meaningful information if the labels are just buzzwords without numerical values

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible using the Chart functionality available in Google Sheets.

What you would have to do is add drawings containing textboxes with the labels you want using the `Insert > Drawing` menu item, like so:

[image]

#### What you can do:

You can file a feature request for axis labelling of radar charts by following the `Help > Help Sheets improve` menu item, then clicking `Suggest and idea` on the right sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is possible. The first column should contain labels to display at the "peaks" and the second should contain values. Then, in "Edit chart -> Setup" choose "Use column A as labels".

[image: example of a chart]